# ember property.length works when accessed from template, but is undefined when accessed from controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

Please see:
 http://jsbin.com/UZETowi/3/edit

This code runs fine locally on my computer, but doesn't run in JSBin for some reason.  What's wrong?

Here's my problem: accessing items.length from the handlebars template produced the correct answer, but when I tried to output same value via console.log, I get "undefined."  Why is this?

Comment: Can you post the Code in the Question please? You can do it with the 'Code Sample' button. The button looks like this '{ }'

Comment: Code can be accessed via the jsbin link shown in the post.

Answer (score 1):

add the length inside of the getter, items is a collection, not an array, so it doesn't have the length property defined on the object itself.

```
 console.log (this.get('items.length'));
```

http://jsbin.com/obEmOfuB/2/edit

Comment: Thank you; it worked.

Do you know why the code I posted in jsbin fails to run?  When I post code relating to questions, I always get the code to run locally first, then copy over to jsbin or jfiddle.  But at least half the time, I struggle to get code to run on those 2 platforms.

Comment: You need to point your js files to either a CDN or somewhere that doesn't deliver the file as TEXT/HTML.  http://cdnjs.com/ is really good, additionally you can start off with a templated version of ember at emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: @ptmoy2 Your JQuery is too modern Error: assertion failed: Ember Views require jQuery 1.7 (>= 1.7.2) or 1.8
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js
Line 52 and what kingpin2k had said also

Comment: To Edu: but I used the latest version of jquery locally without getting this error.

Comment: It has nothing to do with jquery, it's because jsbin doesn't like when you access js files that are delivered as text/html.  It throws the error in the console.  http://jsbin.com/obEmOfuB/2/edit